# Configure <XMP> with styles

Tags: html, css

i got a problem with tag `<xmp>` i cant configure it for auto scalling. What styles i should use for that xmp? I want to auto scalling with width of the page.

[image: xmp problem]

Comment: [You shouldn't use xmp](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#non-conforming-features)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it. Why not use `<div>`